# rust program runs incredibly slow

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio

I have written the following program out of curiousity. It ticks X amount of times every second, and it should be very close to the aimed tick count, but somehow it always lacks behind a lot.

For example for a 2 second benchmark the output is (it should be 2*64 -> 128). Building in release mode doesn't help the issue:

```
Starting benchmark 2s with length
Benchmark started.
Ticked 83 in 2 seconds
```

It is the same for other lenghts, for example 5 second yields 196 which should be 320. It should be actually more cause I let it run a little bit more.

Is it because of `Arc Mutex` being slow, or is there anything more to this? Where is the bottleneck?

```
use std::{ time::{ SystemTime, UNIX_EPOCH }, sync::Arc };

use tokio::{ time::{ sleep, Duration }, sync::Mutex };

const TICK_COUNT: u64 = 64;
const BENCHMARK_LENGTH: u64 = 2;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let tick_count = 0;
    let interval = 1000 / TICK_COUNT;

    let shared = Arc::new(Mutex::new(tick_count));

    let start_time = SystemTime::now();

    println!("Starting benchmark {}s with length", BENCHMARK_LENGTH);

    let displayed = shared.clone();
    let incrementer = shared.clone();

    tokio::spawn(async move {
        loop {
            if
                start_time.duration_since(UNIX_EPOCH).unwrap() +
                    Duration::from_secs(BENCHMARK_LENGTH) <
                SystemTime::now().duration_since(UNIX_EPOCH).unwrap()
            {
                println!("Ticked {} in {} seconds", displayed.lock().await, BENCHMARK_LENGTH);

                std::process::exit(0);
            }

            sleep(Duration::from_millis(500)).await;
        }
    });

    tokio::spawn(async move {
        loop {
            sleep(Duration::from_millis(interval)).await;

            *incrementer.lock().await += 1;
        }
    });

    let _ = tokio::spawn(async move {
        println!("Benchmark started.");
        loop {
            sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
        }
    }).await;
}
```

Comment: ot: Is there a reason you handroll [`elapsed()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.SystemTime.html#method.elapsed)

Comment: This code does not benchmark the language but the OS scheduler. Most of the activity consists in suspending/resuming the thread (because of the sleep calls).

Comment: should that not be efficiently handled by tokio?

Comment: no particular reason, except that I didnt know another way, since I am just learning rust

Comment: @geo10 the OS? handled by tokio?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant, that the suspension and resuming of threads is scheduled by tokio in this case if I am not mistaken

Comment: You are mistaken, `tokio` at best handles tasks, not threads.

Comment: I think I understand the bottleneck here based on your input. I should be running this on a dedicated thread that doesn nothing but this, basically never going to sleep just checking the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your program on my computer.
Duplicating the `*incrementer.lock().await += 1;` statements does not change the behaviour (the count is simply multiplied consequently), thus the slowdown is not due to the `Mutex`.
Moreover, I replaced the `Mutex` by an atomic integer, and the behaviour is still the same.

`cargo flamegraph` reports a lot of time spent in a system-call below `ThreadParker::futex_wait()` (of `parking_lot`), which confirms the intuition I expressed in the comment: most of the time is spent in the OS suspending/resuming the underlying thread of the `tokio` runtime.

About the numerical values, I obtain 122 ticks in 2s, not far from the 128 expected.
With 128 `TICK_COUNT`, I obtain 240 in 2s instead of 256 and with 256 `TICK_COUNT`, I obtain 466 in 2s instead of 512.
This is not ideal, but not very far from the expected values.
Maybe your OS is not as reactive as mine? (I use a quite usual Linux)